# If Image Is Larger Than Container, Add Class

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

Ok so I've been at this for hours to no avail. What I want to do, is write a script that does the following: when an image is larger than it's container, it adds the class "large" to it. But, if an image is smaller than it's container, it adds the class small to it. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var screenImage = $('.image img');

// Create new offscreen image to test
var theImage = new Image();
theImage.src = screenImage.attr('src');

// Get accurate measurements from that.
var imageWidth = theImage.width;

// Find post width
var postWidth = $('.image').innerWidth();

$('.image img').each(function() {
    if (imageWidth > postWidth) {
        $('.image').find('img').addClass('large');
    } else {
        $('.image').find('img').addClass('small');
    }
});
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheInfection/6fUgr/8

Instead, the end result for this script is that all images get the "large" class added to them. I've spent hours on Google, the jQuery website, etc. and I couldn't find the solution anywhere. Could someone help me?

Comment: There is no element with class `post` in your Fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4Kbe/)

```
var postWidth = $('.post').innerWidth();
$('.image img').removeClass('large, small') ;
    $('.image img').each(function() {

        var imageWidth = this.width;
        if (imageWidth > postWidth) {
            $(this).addClass('large');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('small');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This was really starting to get to me :P

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes in your logic, as far as I understood:

1. `$('.image img')` this selects **more than 1** image objects, so the `src` property would not be the one, that is expected.
2. You should recalculate the size of **each** image and assign a class to **one** image object. `$('.image').find('img').addClass('large');` assigns `.large` class to **every image**.

This **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/6fUgr/16/)** shows the proper usage of `.each(function(idx, item)` method for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're trying to do is cap the width of any image(s) inside your element `.post`.

You can achieve this using the CSS property `max-width`, which became available in CSS2:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

**Browser Support**

Unless you need to support ie6 and lower, this should be fine - there's a polyfill available even if you do:

http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh

---

**See it in action**

http://jsfiddle.net/vonky/NYF2v/

**Markup - HTML**

```
<div class="post">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <br /><br />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
</div>
```

**Markup - CSS**

```
.post {
    width: 300px; /* cap the width of our DIV.post */
    margin: 0 auto; /* for visual reference, let's center our element */
    background-color: #00B2EE; /* for visual reference, let's make it blue */
    text-align: center; /* for visual reference, let's center our content */
}

.post img {
    max-width: 100%; /* this is the magical faerie dust */
}
```

If you are adding the classes for another reason and *need* the classes added, PSL's initial script looks like it should work.